# How can i enable Hystrix.stream

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, hystrix

How can i enable Hystrix.stream in my micro service through configuration and not annonation

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableHystrix
public class SpringCloudApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
SpringApplication.run(SpringCloudApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

But  i want to do it with config/application.properties

Comment: Not currently possibly

Comment: @spencergibb can i enable it with a spring configuration file and add EnableHystrix annotation to it? (i can't annotate the main function)

Comment: There annotation just needs to be on on `@Configuration`, doesn't have to be on the main class. Then that configuration could be enabled or not with a property